# Laravel 5 Timestamp is NULL

Tags: laravel, timestamp

Yesterday, in Migration, my code is

```
$table->timestamp();
```

in Database, table will have 2 columns `created_at` and `updated_at` with CURRENT_TIME

But today, when I run migration again, 2 columns are NULL value. When I add new row it still NULL value, not CURRENT_TIME.

Please tell me why I got this bug?

Comment: Please note that `updated_at` is always 0000-00-00 00:00:00 upon creation, `created_at` column should have DEFAULT property set to CURRENT_TIME. See http://i.stack.imgur.com/4Lfq9.png; do check your database structure by hand, and write back what DEFAULT values do `created_at` and `updated_at` have in your table.

Comment: @Kyslik I created migration to creating table (id and timestamp is auto created). I run migration in cmd and than, table is created. last month `created_at` is CURRENT time. but now, it's not. WHY? new version???
Thank alot for supporting me!

Answer (score 3):

You missed the `s`. So, try it with `$table->timestamps();`

When you mention `$table->timestamp();` then you have to give the column name in the argument.

Comment: Thanks, but I found that the cause is version, new version 5.27~ timestamps is null when you run `migrate`. in my code `timestamps` has `s`. thanks so much.